# Tell position of string in document

Tags: python

This code works to print the line number which contains the given string:

```
import os

f = open('document.xml', 'r+')

for (i, line) in enumerate(f, start=1):
    if "<w:t>Omg" in line: print(i)
```

but I want to know how much characters are in the document before the string starts. So I thought being a smartass and changed it to this:

```
import os

f = open('document.xml', 'r+')

for (i, line) in enumerate(f, start=1):
    if "<w:t>Omg" in line: print(f.tell())
```

but this throws an error:

```
if "<w:t>Omg" in line: print(f.tell())

OSError: telling position disabled by next() call
```

I can not use the line number for what I want to do, because it has to work with generated xml documents, without newlines, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update file position in a loop:

```
target = "<w:t>Omg"
offset = 0
for line in f:
    if target in line:
        print(offset + line.find(target))
    offset += len(line)
```

Or, don't depend on iteration-on-file (which use `next`), and use `readline` or `read` method of the file object; then, you can use `file.tell` method.

```
target = "<w:t>Omg"
offset = 0
while True:
    offset = f.tell()
    line = f.readline()
    if not line:
        break
    if target in line:
        print(offset + line.find(target))
```

Comment: If I'm not wrong he needs to know how many characters are from 1 to the start of the string, and this doesn't give that output. This means if you have `"asdH<w:t>Omg"` it must output `3`.

Comment: @Borja, Thank you for pointing that out. I updated the answer accordingly.